# Display multiple images from array using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display three Objects image properties in a single container using document.getElementById. My code only displays the first image.  Is this possible, or am i going about this the wrong way?

```
var flop =  function(){

document.getElementById("flop").innerHTML = (deck[0].image);
document.getElementById("flop").innerHTML = (deck[1].image);
document.getElementById("flop").innerHTML = (deck[2].image);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var flop = function(){
 var temp = document.getElementById("flop")
 deck.forEach(function(val){
   temp.innerHTML += val.image
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
var flop =  function(){
  document.getElementById("flop").innerHTML = (deck[0].image);
  document.getElementById("flop").innerHTML += (deck[1].image); //See the +
  document.getElementById("flop").innerHTML += (deck[2].image);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need append the new content, but your code init the content with a new value every time, so it only containe the last value.
you can try the following code:

```
var flop =  function(){
    document.getElementById("flop").innerHTML = (deck[0].image);
    document.getElementById("flop").innerHTML += (deck[1].image);
    document.getElementById("flop").innerHTML += (deck[2].image);
}
```